# The basic of the count

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> (a) A computer network consists of six computers. Each computer is directly connected
>   to at least one of the other computers. Show that there are at least two computers in
>   the network that are directly connected to the same number of other computers.
>
> (b) Find the least number of cables required to connect eight computers to four printers
>   to guarantee that four computers can directly access four different printers. Justify
>   your answer.

Comment: These are lovely questions. So, what have you done? What do *you* think about them?

Comment: For (a) How can I show that there at least two computers direct connected to the number of computers since its already mention that each computer directly connected to at least one of the other?

Answer (score 2):

HINTS:

1. Pick any one of the six computers; to how many others can it be connected? We’re told that it’s connected to at least one, and there are only five others, so it must be connected to $1,2,3,4$, or $5$ other computers. The same is true of each of the six. That’s how many different possibilities?
2. This problem is very poorly worded. It could mean that there are at least four computers, each of which can access all four printers; that there is some set of four computers that altogether can access all four printers; or that no matter what four computers you pick, those four can access all four printers. I suspect, however, that the last of these is intended, since the first two are trivial. The best way to attack it is probably to ask yourself how many cables you can install **without** meeting the requirement. For instance, is you connect each of the eight computers to the same three printers, you’ve used $8\cdot3=24$ cables, and **no** set of four computers can access all four printers. How much worse can you do? How many more cables can you install and still have at least one set of four computers that can reach at most three of the printers?

Answer (score 2):

By Pigeonhole principle:

the connections each computer can have is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 (these are 5 holes)

the number of computers is 6 (these are pigeons)

therefore, there will be at least 2 computers having same number of connections

Answer (score 0):

(a) There are six computers, and each computer connected to at least one of the other five computers, this means the possible connection for each computer is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, by using the Pigeon and Pigeonhole Principle, let these 5 possible connections be the Pigeonholes, and let the six computers be the Pigeons, therefore there are must at least two computers have same number of connections.

(b) First, think of the worse case, there are 8 computers and 4 printers, so the worst case would be all 8 computers have access to 3 printers, but non of them have access to 4 printers, that is $8\times3=24$ cables. Now, since each computer has access to 3 printers, then you can just add 4 cables, so that there must be 4 computers have access to all 4 printers. Thus, the number of cables that guarantee 4 computers have direct access to all 4 printers is $24+4=28$

Answer (score 0):

As for b)
I was doing exercises in the Discrete Mathematics and Its Application book and stumbled across the same exercise, my solution was to connect five computers to all four printers at the total use of cables to 5*4 = 20, then there is no way to pick four computers without picking at least one which is connected to all four printers.

As far as I can tell the part with the computer connected to each other is only for exercise a).